# Plotting fmax v/s ID/W (current density) in cadence

Tags: cadence

I want to plot a graph of fmax v/s current density in cadence. I plan to use the s-parameter analysis but I am unaware of how to plot the ID/W term on x axis. I would be grateful if anybody could share some details. In the sweep options of the sp analysis I am only allowed to select one parameter, and since both ID and W are from 2 different components, it is hard to figure out. I am sharing a snap of my test bench.

Thank you

I tried exploring options to plot ID/W term but could not succeed.
[image: Test Bench for simulation]

Comment: Hey, did you figure this out? I am trying to get Ids vs current density too. I am not sure if my schematic is correct...

Comment: can you mail me on yash.hemant.shah@gmail.com ?